# Java Array Wrap Around

Tags: java, arrays, word-wrap

Hi i wondering to on how to wrap an array

for example take the array below:

```
|00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07|
```

say i wanted to move everything right, to get to this:

```
|07  00  01  02  03  04  05  06|
```

how do i do this without losing any of data?

to move things to the right i am currently using this code:

```
public void transform(IFrame frame) {

    char tempImage;

    for (int i = 0; i < frame.getNumRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < frame.getNumRows(); j++) {

            tempImage = frame.getChar(i,j);

            frame.setChar(i+1, j, tempImage);
}
```

essentially what i want the code to do in very basic terms is:

- go through each row/column (the frame.getNumRows , as the frame is square the rows/columns are the same
- get the char value of i and j from the frame

-with that frame, set the frame char value of i and j to be i+1 whilst keeping j the same

-with the character to be set being the temp image

***UPDATE***

I have implemented this method and changed it from the previous one posted, below is the updated code:

```
public void transform(IFrame frame) {

        char constantImage;

        for (int i = 0; i < frame.getNumRows(); i++) { //go through each row/column
            for (int j = 0; j < frame.getNumRows(); j++) {

                constantImage = frame.getChar(i, j);

                TransformFrames.add(constantImage);

                Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(TransformFrames), 1);


                for (Character f : TransformFrames) {
                    frame.setChar(i, j, f);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

TransformFrames is a character array list.

Through debugging i can see that the correct data is being added to the array list, and i hope being moved across however i am unable to see this happening as the gui is not updating once this method is called - any suggestions why or how to fix??

Thanks

Comment: While you can certainly do this with an array, I'd advise an `ArrayList`. That way to "wrap" all you need to do is `.remove` the last element then `.add` it to the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is [Collections.rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-):

```
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), 1);
```

Comment: Note that primitives cannot be used with this method; their boxed, wrapper classes are required.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, one well-known solution is this:

You have

```
|00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07|
```

Add the same array to the end again:

```
|00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07 00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07|
```

Now, the array wrapped around the index `i` is just the sub-array of this new array starting at the index `i` and having the same length as your initial array:

```
01  02  03  04  05  06  07 00

02  03  04  05  06  07 00  01

03  04  05  06  07 00  01  02
```

etc

Comment: how would something like this be implemented around the given code above?

Comment: You could use extra space to get the array using an ArrayList<> maybe and copy the required characters from this to the array.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>First of all, this is likely an "XY Problem". You have some problem to solve, which you have told us nothing about, you *think* what you need to do in order to solve your problem is rotating an array, (yes, *rotating* is the term used for this,) and you are asking us how to rotate an array. (See: http://xyproblem.info) In other words, you are asking us to solve some "X" problem, while in fact what you want to solve is some "Y" problem that came before it, so it would have been beneficial for all involved to tell us about the "Y" problem instead. But, let's move on with the question.</sup>

The problem of overwriting the elements that you want to move is a well known problem, with a well known solution:

- If you want to rotate to the left, copy elements from left to right, that is, **ascending**.
- If you want to rotate to the right, copy elements from right to left, that is, **descending**.

That's all there is to it.

And then of course, in java, there is `System.arrayCopy()`, which will do that for you without you having to re-invent the wheel.